# Coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm using a simple context manager with an asyncio loop inside:

```
class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.loop.close()

    def do_work(self):
        ...
        return self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))
```

When I use two Runner objects, I get "Coroutine was never awaited" error.

```
with Runner() as r:
    r.do_work()

with Runner() as r2:
    r2.do_work()
```

Because a loop was closed in the first Runner(r). Everything works if I don't close a loop in **exit**, but I don't need to keep it opened. I know that we can have only one loop in a thread, but why it doesn't wait for run_until_complete?

Comment: Have you tried initializing the loop in the `__enter__()` method? There you can also track if one loop is already running.

Comment: Please edit the answer to include a _runnable_ minimal example that still shows the problem. (E.g. use `asyncio.sleep()` for a future, and so on.) That will make it much easier to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

> why it doesn't wait for run_until_complete

Probably something like this happens:

```
import asyncio


async def test():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.run_until_complete(test())
    loop.close()

    loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

Result:

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test' was never awaited
```

### How to solve this issue?

Since you're using event loop this way, you can just use new [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoopPolicy.new_event_loop) each time:

```
class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()  # *new*_event_loop


    def do_work(self):
        # Make sure all futures are created 
        # with relevant event loop been set as current
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

        # ...
        return self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))
```