# asncio coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am attempting to run an experiment with 2 coroutines with asyncio. One loop is to scrape a weather data outside air temperature and the other loop is just a made up value with numpy random. Both coroutines have the same traceback nothing happens..

`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_weather' was never awaited`

Would anyone have any ideas to try? I am trying to follow this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579094/coroutine-was-never-awaited) for a similar question as well as this other [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399157/runtimewarning-coroutine-main-was-never-awaited) for running python 3.7 with coroutines which I am doing.

```
import asyncio
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

async def get_weather():
    await asyncio.sleep(300)

    r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=weather%20duluth', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    outTemp = soup.find("span", {"class": "wob_t"}).text
    intOutTemp = int(outTemp)
    print(f'got outside temperature data {intOutTemp}')
    return intOutTemp


async def get_temp():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

    inTemp = (random.random() * 20) - 5  # -5 to 15
    print(f'got inside temperature data {inTemp}')
    return temperature


def main():
    loop1 = get_weather()
    loop2 = get_temp()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***UPDATED CODE***

```
#py weatherAsyncio3.py

import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

async def get_weather():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1800)

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=weather%20duluth', headers=headers) as r:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(await r.text(), 'html.parser')
                outTemp = soup.find("span", {"class": "wob_t"}).text
                intOutTemp = int(outTemp)
                print(f'got outside temperature data {intOutTemp}')
                return intOutTemp

async def get_temp():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        inTemp = (random.random() * 20) - 5  # -5 to 15
        print(f'got inside temperature data {inTemp}')
        return inTemp

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futureWeather = asyncio.ensure_future(get_weather())
    loop.run_until_complete(futureWeather)

    futureTemp = asyncio.ensure_future(get_temp())
    loop.run_until_complete(futureTemp)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just created a variable called loop1 & loop2. Neither of them wait for the task to complete. To use as asyncio.run() as an entry point, you can pass in your async methods into asyncio.gather() method to wait for both tasks to complete.

To run method in infinite loop, you can use the *while True:* method and not return from the method. I would recommend either splitting out the logic into 2 methods or renaming GetWeather() to something like GetWeatherContinuously(). It make other users aware of what the code does without looking through the logic.

Also request.get() does not run in parallel. Google returns the results instantly. However if you point the URL to somewhere that has a considerable wait, the issue is noticeable. Therefore I'd strongly recommend using aiohttp.

Also there is issue on Windows whereby aiohttp.get() throws an error - "Event Loop is closed". Therefore as a workaround found on [GitHub](https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914). Therefore I've add commented-out code a call asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()) before asyncio.run(). Only use it, if you need it.

Below is a working example:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

def Logger(json_message):
    print(json.dumps(json_message))

async def get_weather():
    Logger({"start": "get_weather()"})
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)    
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            r = await session.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=weather%20duluth', headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(await r.text(), 'html.parser')
            outTemp = soup.find("span", {"class": "wob_t"}).text
            intOutTemp = int(outTemp)

            Logger({"results": f'got outside temperature data {intOutTemp}'})
            Logger({"finish": "get_weather()"})
            #return intOutTemp # without a return, the while loop will run continuously.

async def get_temperature():
    Logger({"start": "get_temperature()"})
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        inTemp = (random.random() * 20) - 5  # -5 to 15
        Logger({"results": f'got inside temperature data {inTemp}'})
        Logger({"finish": "get_temperature()"})
        #return inTemp # without a return, the while loop will run continuously.

async def main():
    statements = [get_weather(), get_temperature()]
    Logger({"start": "gather()"})

    await asyncio.gather(*statements) # Gather is used to allow both funtions to run at the same time.
    Logger({"finish": "gather()"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()) # Use this to stop "Event loop is closed" error on Windows - https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: @greg thanks for the post/answer. The script works but would you know how I could keep the script running in an infinite loop? I added some `while True` statements and adjusted the ascio sleep times... In my Post for `UPDATED CODE` it appears to run but not print any values... Would you have any ideas to make your code run infinate?

Comment: I've just updated the code to have one entry for asyncio.run(). The script should only print  once. One possibility for running the code infinitely is to call main() after main has been been completed. I'm not sure why you would want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Any chance you could tell me the difference using `requests` Vs `aiohttp`?

Comment: Greg, thanks for addressing my comment, it's appreciated! I suspect, though, that HenryHub will be disappointed upon noticing that the call to `requests.get()` in `get_weather` and anything in `get_temp` aren't actually running in parallel. `get_weather` should either use aiohttp to obtain the data or at least use `loop.run_in_executor` to execute `requests.get` off-thread and allow the event loop to proceed executing other coroutines.

Comment: @user4815162342 It looks like there is a bug in aiohttp, whereby "Event loop is closed" (https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324), so I've put the request.get() back in. Like you've mention there are some good work arounds. get_weather() & get_temp() should run in parallel. If you change the timeout to be say 10 seconds longer add some print statements you should see them running at the same time.

Comment: If you use `requests.get` without `run_in_executor`, it will **not** run in parallel with anything else. Tweaking sleeps and timeouts won't make a difference there simply because asyncio is single-threaded. The bug you've linked seems specific to a non-default event loop on Windows and should not be relevant to the usability of aiohttp, which is the go-to async http library, used by thousands of users worldwide. (Also, the maintainer's comment indicates that the issue was fixed in a later aiohttp release.)

Comment: @user4815162342 that was a good spot. When I ran the code using aiohttp I was getting "Event loop is closed" error, but fixed it using  asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy()) (https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914)

Comment: You might want to prefix the event loop policy change with `if sys.platform == 'win32'`. As written, I believe the code will fail to execute on non-Windows operating systems.

Comment: @Greg im sort of a novice at best.. Can you help me understand (which I am starting to learn javascript & JSON) why do you print json dumps instead of just print python console? Its the `logger` function... Thanks again for the answer & posting...

Comment: @HenryHub It sounds like you've got the answer, but I've update my code again to have a contentiously loop. It's just simple "while True:" and don't return (as that will complete the while loop. It's fine to print string. However I always create a logger as part of SOLID principles (see Single responsibility and Open/Close principles). The logic has nothing to do with get weather data. Furthermore we can change the logger to write somewhere else without altering the getWeather() method (e.g write to file).

Comment: Also by using JSON, it allows for separation of the details. E.g in AWS lambdas, I have thousands of logged entries and I can create an activity based on Json property "Exception", which then sends out an email, with the details.

Comment: @HenryHub if you put a brek point on you update code on the line futureTemp = asyncio.ensure_future(get_temp()) - this will not fire until futureWeather has completed.By calling gather(), the methods both run at the same time.

Comment: @user4815162342 if sys.platform == 'win32' will work, but the code base should run exactly the same across all environments (e.g dev, staging, prod). There should be a decision to either set the policy or not. So I've commented it out for non Windows users.